# How to create 2D array from a function output

Tags: python, arrays

The following function creates a 3 bit adder truth table. How can I get an 2D array structure from the output?

```
import numpy as np
def truthTable(inputs=3):
    if inputs == 3:
        print("  A B C S Cout ")
        for a in range(0, 2):
            for b in range(0, 2):
                for c in range(0, 2):
                        cout = eval("((a & b) | (a & c) | (b & c))")
                        s = eval("(a ^ b ^ c)")
                        print(str(a) + "," + str(b) + "," + str(c) + "," + str(s) + "," + str(cout))

truthTable()
```

couurent o/p:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,0
0,1,0,1,0
0,1,1,0,1
1,0,0,1,0
1,0,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,1
1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Perhaps you can append all the values and then do np.reshape to a 8 by 5 matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
def truthTable(inputs=3):
    if inputs == 3:
        print("  A B C S Cout ")
        tt = []
        for a in range(0, 2):
            for b in range(0, 2):
                for c in range(0, 2):
                        cout = eval("((a & b) | (a & c) | (b & c))")
                        s = eval("(a ^ b ^ c)")
                        tt.append([a, b, c, s, cout])
        return tt

print(truthTable())
```

`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
def get_cout(a,b,c):
    return eval("((a & b) | (a & c) | (b & c))")
def get_s(a,b,c):
    return eval("(a ^ b ^ c)")
all_booleans  = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
for i in all_booleans:
    print(f"{str(i[0])},{str(i[1])},{str(i[2])},{str(get_s(i[0],i[1],i[2]))},{str(get_cout(i[0],i[1],i[2]))}")
```

Output:

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,0
0,1,0,1,0
0,1,1,0,1
1,0,0,1,0
1,0,1,0,1
1,1,0,0,1
1,1,1,1,1
```